# Is there a way to find out how much space (in bytes) an SQLite table needs?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with say 10 tables filled.
I would like to find out how many bytes a specific table is using.

Is there a way to find out with an SQL Statement or a tool ?

I could simply export the table to an empty database and check the file size, but I am looking for an more elegant way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sqlite3_analyzer.exe`. You can download it from [the official site](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: bit late :-) . Thanks a lot.